Establishing ssh connection using QProcess in Qt-creator
I am trying to create an application that connects to my raspberry pi via ssh and lists the stuff in it's home directory. The problem is that it says "process not started" and I don't understand why the process won't start.
//this button should start the ssh process
void MainWindow::on_connectButton_clicked()
{
    //this is where the desired command is given to the application
    QProcess process;
    process.start("ssh -i /home/usr/ssh_key pi@pi_ip_address ls"); //command to be executed
    
    //if-statement that checks wether the process has started
    if (process.waitForStarted()) {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Info", "process started");
    }
    else{
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Info", "process not started");
    }

    //reads the output of the command and errors
    QString output = process.readAllStandardOutput();
    QString error = process.readAllStandardError();

    //puts the errors and output into messageBoxes
    if (error.isEmpty()) {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Command output", output);
    }
    else {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "command error", error);
    }
}

Here are the included libraries:
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QProcess>
#include <string>
#include <QInputDialog>
#include <libssh2.h>
#include <QFile>
#include <libssh2_sftp.h>

I tried the program with commands like "ls", "pwd" and "whoami" and they all worked, so I am quite confused. I also ran the ssh command in terminal and it worked. I am very new to this so any help and tips are welcome. Thank you in advance.

If the process starts successfully, QProcess will emit started(); otherwise, errorOccurred() will be emitted. Do note that on platforms that are able to start child processes synchronously (notably Windows), those signals will be emitted before this function returns and this QProcess object will transition to either QProcess::Running or QProcess::NotRunning state, respectively. On others paltforms, the started() and errorOccurred() signals will be delayed. Link

Does it fail instantly, or after the default delay of waitForStarted() (30 seconds)? In the first case, inspect its error(). Note that you should never use blocking functions in the main gui thread. Besides, readAllStandardOutput() and readAllStandardError() are QByteArrays.
